# Rmagick failed to build gem native on OSX Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I am trying to work on my gallery, and I need to install rmagick. However I have been unable to do so as I am getting a error with a fail to build gem native extension. I have see the other postings but their errors are different from mines.

I am not sure how to get it to work. If someone knows a fix that would be of great help!

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/lexi87/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for snprintf() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AcquireImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AffinityImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AffinityImages() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AutoGammaImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AutoLevelImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for BlueShiftImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for ConstituteComponentTerminus() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DeskewImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for EncipherImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for EqualizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for FloodfillPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for FunctionImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetAuthenticIndexQueue() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetVirtualPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelImageColors() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelColorsImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LiquidRescaleImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for MagickLibAddendum() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for OpaquePaintImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for QueueAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for RemapImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for RemoveImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SelectiveBlurImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetMagickMemoryMethods() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SparseColorImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SyncAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransformImageColorspace() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransparentPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransparentPaintImageChroma() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for QueryMagickColorname() new signature... yes
checking for Image.type in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.kerning in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interline_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interword_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DitherMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for MagickFunction in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for long double in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.CopyAlphaChannel... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.BackgroundAlphaChannel... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.BlurCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.DistortCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearBurnCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearDodgeCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.MathematicsCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PegtopLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PinLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.VividLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT1Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT3Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT5Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.ZipSCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.PizCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.Pxr24Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44ACompression... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelInverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearForwardDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearReverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.DePolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolynomialDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.ShepardsDistortion... yes
checking for DitherMethod.NoDitherMethod... yes
checking for FilterTypes.KaiserFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.WelshFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.ParzenFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.LagrangeFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BohmanFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BartlettFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.SentinelFilter... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PowEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LogEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdBlackEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdWhiteEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.GaussianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ImpulseNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LaplacianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.MultiplicativeNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PoissonNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.UniformNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.CosineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.SineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.AddModulusEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArcsinFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArctanFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.PolynomialFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.SinusoidFunction... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.FlattenLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MergeLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MosaicLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.TrimBoundsLayer... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.CheckerTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_frame_this_func() in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile


======================================================================
Thu 28Feb13 20:39:13
This installation of RMagick 2.13.2 is configured for
Ruby 1.9.3 (x86_64-darwin12.2.0) and ImageMagick 6.8.0 Q16 
======================================================================



make
compiling rmagick.c
compiling rmdraw.c
compiling rmenum.c
compiling rmfill.c
compiling rmilist.c
rmilist.c: In function ‘ImageList_map’:
rmilist.c:448: warning: ‘MapImages’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/magick/deprecate.h:200)
compiling rmimage.c
rmimage.c: In function ‘Image_map’:
rmimage.c:8159: warning: ‘MapImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/magick/deprecate.h:198)
rmimage.c: In function ‘Image_recolor’:
rmimage.c:10705: warning: ‘RecolorImage’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/magick/deprecate.h:140)
compiling rminfo.c
compiling rmmain.c
compiling rmmontage.c
compiling rmpixel.c
compiling rmstruct.c
compiling rmutil.c
rmutil.c: In function ‘rm_fatal_error_handler’:
rmutil.c:1612: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
rmutil.c: In function ‘handle_exception’:
rmutil.c:1652: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
linking shared-object RMagick2.bundle
ld: file not found: /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RMagick2.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this I had to uninstall then reinstall RVM. Then run 'brew install ruby' to get the latest version. Then 'bundle'.

I hope this helps others who ran into the exact error I did.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're missing a shared library called `libltdl` which is required for building the gem. A quick Google search shows that this is provided by the [libtool package](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libltdl.html).

1. Try installing libtool and see if that fixes the problem. If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), this can be done with `brew install libtool`.
2. Apparently, there is a [known issue](https://github.com/lolcommits/lolcommits/issues/65) on Mountain Lion where the suggested solution is to: update XCode to 4.4, update the XCode command line tools, install XQuartz (probably not required for this), and finally:

   ```
    brew uninstall imagemagick
    brew install --fresh imagemagick
   ```

Comment: There is a [known issue](https://github.com/mroth/lolcommits/issues/65#issuecomment-7280659) on Mountain Lion, but I'm not sure if that solution would help you since you say you're on Lion.

Comment: Also, your make log shows that it's looking for `libltdl` in the `/usr/local/lib` directory, but I'm guessing there isn't anything in there?

Comment: Could you run `find /usr -name 'libltdl.7.dylib'` and see if anything comes up? If so, you could try manually creating the symlink to this file inside `/usr/local/lib` with something like `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libltdl.7.dylib /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib` assuming that the file exists in the `/usr/lib` directory.

Comment: i had the same problem.
the solution was to link the lib sitting around in the cellar
 ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/lib/libltdl.7.dylib /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
defined here
http://nathan.vertile.com/blog/2013/02/14/installing_rmagick_on_108_with_homebrew/

Answer (score 3):

The missing library is provided by `libtool` package. You can install via brew:

> brew instal libtool

After the installation you get this message:

> Xcode 4.2 and below provide glibtool.
>
> Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
>   own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
>   build variables:
>
> ```
> LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/libtool/lib
> CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/libtool/include
> ```

Add those environment variables to your current environment:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libtool/lib"  
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libtool/include"
```

And then install rmagick gem again. I also have update the XCode command lines tools to the latest version.